# Background video on my web app doesn't show on iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, iphone, background

I have a problem with the background video of my web app. Once deployed I noticed that bg-video does not play on iphone. It is only showing the first frame of the video as a picture and the play button in the middle. Does anyone has any idea?

```
import video from "../assets/video.mp4";

function BgVideo() {
  return (
    <div className="bgvideo">
      <video type="video/mp4" src={video} autoPlay muted loop playsInline />
    </div>
  );
}

export default BgVideo;
```

```
import "./index.scss";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import BgVideo from "./components/BgVideo";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <BgVideo />
    <Navbar />
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

```
.bgvideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/ There's a few links to help, it's a bit of a trick to make it work sometimes depending.